# Solving an equaiton which includes $log$ as both base and exponent

Tags: logarithms

Q:
If
$$9x = x^{\log_3x}$$
then what is $x$ ?

I can't solve it. I have tried to use identities in my book but i think they are useless for this question. I need a hint

Comment: Try taking $\log_3$ of both sides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is $$\log_3(9x)=(\log_3x)^2$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Yes I can. Thank you very much

Comment: @Oğuzİsmayiluysal: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try taking logarithm to the base $3$ on both sides. You'll get a quadratic in $\log_3x$.

Answer (score -1):

Take $\log_3$ of both sides. Then
$$ \log_3{9} + \log_3{x} = (\log_3{x}) (\log_3{x}), $$
using $\log{ab}=\log{a}+\log{b}$ and $\log{a^b} = b\log{a}$. This is a quadratic equation for $\log_3{x}$. Solve that and exponentiate $3$ with the answer to find $x$.